# Sending a value to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, theming

I have set theme handler for a form in Drupal and this handler has a template file.
What is the easiest way to send a value from PHP to JavaScript in that include file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Drupal is with [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6), using the "setting" type:

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => 'value'), 'setting');
```

That will make the variable available on the JS side at Drupal.settings.variableName.

Answer (score 1):

Few more examples on [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7),

It's better to specify your module name while adding JS variable to avoid any issues,

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');
```

In case you want to execute some JS code after the DOM is initialized,

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, the `#attached` key to a form can be used for sending php variable to js.

```
  $my_variable = 'My custom value';
  $form['some-element']['#attached']['js'] = array(
    array(
     'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/script.js',
    ),
    array(
      'data' => array(
        'variable' => $my_variable,
       ),
      'type' => 'setting',
    ),
  );
```

This can be used in `hook_form_alter` for example.

Answer (score -10):

Easiest way is just to echo it out into a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var variableName = <?php echo $variable ?>;
</script>
```

If Drupal uses a templating language, you need to replace the `<?php echo... ?>` with the relevent output method...

Comment: also if variable is a string you should put it in a quotes and escape if needed.

Comment: Scott's suggesting, using Drupal.settings, is definitely the correct way to go for this.

Comment: This is not a drupal standard.